# What is Onetimeinitializer.apk Android application?

Tags: applications

Anyone know purpose or any document about `Onetimeinitializer.apk`? It is a built-in application.

I searched for a while but did not find any information about it.

Does anyone have documentation for it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1069429) it runs the first time you boot up (Cyanogenmod?) and prompts you for what Google Apps to install.